# SQL Aggregate logical operations

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate

Is there a way in T-SQL to aggregate with logical conditions on fields which do not represent single bits?

For example, given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Example       (category int, flags int)
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (1,            1) -- Binary 0001
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES (1,            2) -- Binary 0010
```

I'd like a query that does something similar to:

```
SELECT AND(flags) FROM #Example
GROUP BY Category
-- Expect the result to be 0 because 0001 AND 0010 = 0000

SELECT OR(flags) FROM #Example
GROUP BY Category
-- Expect the result to be 3 because 0010 OR 0001 = 0011
```

On a single bit field I know you can convert to int and then use max and min, but this would only work on single bit values so doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Presumably you won't want to aggregate all rows, just distinct values? "1 or 1 or 1 or 1" is just "1 or 1" etc

Comment: @Stu would that change the result, or would it just be an optimisation?

Comment: No, that's only correct if it's a single bit.  0010 AND 0011 is 0010, but MAX(0010, 0011) is 0011.  0010 OR 0001 is 0011, MIN(0010, 0001) is 0001. NOTE: this was in response to a now deleted comment, but possibly still worth keeping.

Comment: Sorry I deleted it as I was doing some quick tests lol and realised it was not correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not have such an aggregate function. You could create one using SQLCLR.

But an easier option is to split out each bit and aggregate separately, then add them back together.

For `OR`

```sql
SELECT
  MAX(flags & 1) +
  MAX(flags & 2) +
  MAX(flags & 4) +
  MAX(flags & 8)
FROM #Example
GROUP BY Category
```

For `AND`

```sql
SELECT
  MIN(flags & 1) +
  MIN(flags & 2) +
  MIN(flags & 4) +
  MIN(flags & 8)
FROM #Example
GROUP BY Category
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be55c2c7fe36800688f87a615494275c)

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I'm actually only interested in a single flag at a time, so I'd not even have to add them together.