# SQL Server custom CLR aggregate bitwise and

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, bitwise-and

I wrote a custom CLR bitwise-and aggregate function in C#. But it is not working.

It always returns value of the last row in aggregated records.

What's the mistake?

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.Native,
    IsInvariantToOrder = false,
    IsInvariantToNulls = true,
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = false
)]
public struct AggAnd
{
    private long _value;
    public bool IsNull { get; private set; }

    public void Init()
    {
        _value = 0;
        IsNull = false;
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlInt64 value)
    {
        if (!value.IsNull)
        {
            _value = value.Value;
        }
    }

    public void Merge(AggAnd x)
    {
        _value = x._value & _value;
    }

    public SqlInt64 Terminate()
    {
        return new SqlInt64(_value);
    }
}
```

Here is sample SQL to test the function:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (num int, ch char(1))

INSERT INTO @a(num, ch)
VALUES (3, 'a'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'b')

SELECT
    ch, 
    dbo.AggAnd(num) AS [aggregated-and] 
FROM
    @a 
GROUP BY 
    ch
```

The output is as follows:

| ch | aggregated-and |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |

Comment: Relevant [SQL Aggregate logical operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251827/sql-aggregate-logical-operations/71253291#71253291)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!

The `Accumulate()` method should be written this way:

```cs
...
public void Accumulate(SqlInt64 value)
{
   if (!value.IsNull)
   {
       if (_value == 0)
          _value = value.Value;
       else
          _value &= value.Value;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: You are almost right (and are on the right track).  Please note that you are mixing two concepts - "is it the first value?" and "is it null?".  It is possible to have nulls in your table, and you aren't yet handling those.  If all the values are null in a group, do you want to return null or 0?  So, I suggest you add the "handle first value" variable since you will have some problem cases if you don't

Comment: Also, if you don't mind explaining what you want to do with this (what real problem are you trying to solve with it?), I'd appreciate to know more.  Thx